# HQL - comparing dates and objects

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

So I have the following code:

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("select p.festivalDay from Performance p where p.startingTimestamp < :startingTimestamp " +
                                        "and p.endingTimestamp> :endingTimestamp" +
                                        "and p.artist= :artist");
    query.setTimestamp("beginningTimestamp", cal.getTime());
    cal.set(endHour, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinute);
    query.setTimestamp("endingTimestamp", cal.getTime());
    query.setParameter("artist", a);
```

For some reason this query is never returning any results, artist is an object from the Class Artist, festivalDay is one of FestivalDay.

Both the timestamp comparisons and artist comparisons seem to be failing (I tried the query with just the timestamps and I tried it with just the artist). ("a" is obviously an Artist object)

This is my model for Performance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_Performance")
public class Performance{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private Date startingTimestamp;
private Date endingTimestamp;
private Date soundCheckUur;  
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "podiumId")
private Podium podium;
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "artistId", nullable = false)
private Artist artist;
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "festivalDayId", nullable = false)
private FestivalDay festivalDay;

public Optreden(){

}

public Optreden(Date startingTimestamp, Date endingTimestamp, Date soundCheckHour) {
    this.startingTimestamp = startingTimestamp;
    this.endingTimestamp = endingTimestamp;
    this.soundCheckHour = soundCheckHour;
}

public void setPodium(Podium podium) {
    this.podium = podium;
}

public void setArtist(Artist artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
}

public void setFestivalDay(FestivalDay festivalDay) {
    this.festivalDay = festivalDay;
}
}
```

There is nothing wrong with my model, I have changed some names to their English versions so if you think you spot an error in the model I probably just forgot to translate it.

Comment: I guess the `o.festivalDay` used in the query is a typo. It should have been `p.festivalDay`, isn't it?!

Comment: You set wron parameter name - beginTijdstip

Comment: What is the generated SQL query? Does the artist passed as parameter have an ID? Have you checked that there indeed was a row satisfying the criteria?

Comment: oh yes it was p.festivalDay, my bad.

Comment: Same for the parameter

Comment: This is the query :

Hibernate: insert into T_ARTIST(name) values (?)
Hibernate: select festivalda1_.id as id1_2_, festivalda1_.date as date2_2_, festivalda1_.festivalId as festival3_2_ from T_PERFORMANCE performance0_ inner join T_FESTIVALDAY festivalda1_ on performance0_.festivaldayId=festivalda1_.id where performance0_.startingTimestamp<? and performance0_.endingTimestamp>? and performance0_.artistId=?

Comment: The artist has an Id, and there is indeed a row satisfying the criteria yes

Comment: I was able to fix the artist part, now it's just the dates that are giving me problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I forgot that December is the 11th month to Java and not 12th... :(